# Do I have to repay the First-Time Homebuyers tax credit if I refinance?

Tags: united-states, taxes, home-ownership, refinance, tax-credit

My wife and I bought our first home in April 2010 and received the full $8000 First-Time Homebuyers tax credit. We now want to refinance, given that the current mortgage rates are significantly lower than they were even just a year and a half ago.

However, it occurred to us that if we did so, would we have to repay the credit? From what I've read, it sounds like no (we're not moving), but since refinancing is technically like closing again, we just want to make sure. I haven't been able to find a definitive answer to this, so any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Homebuyers Tax Credit was unrelated to whether or not a mortgage was part of the purchase. You will have no issue with this credit if you refinance.

Answer (score 0):

No. As long as you live in the house for 3 years, it's yours to keep. Financing has nothing to do with that.